# button to start and stop my code in javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a stop and start button for my code. So I can break the working the source code does.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    var i = 0;
    var path = new Array();

    // LIST OF IMAGES
    path[0] = "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/31/11738-ssj_goku.jpg";
    path[1] = "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/arjw8wqvwnihalb6fq3k.png";
    path[2] = "http://orig03.deviantart.net/8999/f/2013/167/1/7/sword_art_online_by_sakimichan-d69cxwk.jpg";

    function swapImage() {
        document.slide.src = path[i];

        if (i < path.length - 1)
            i++;
        else
            i = 0;

        setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);
    }

    window.onload=swapImage;
</script>

<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
```

Comment: you need to be more specific about what you're asking. This question could be answered in many different ways

Comment: It is better form to write `setTimeout(swapImage, 3000);`.

Answer (score 1):

This will define a variable (running) and toggle between true and false on click of the toggle link:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript">
var running = true;
var i = 0;
var path = new Array();

// LIST OF IMAGES
path[0] = "http://static.giantbomb.com/uploads/original/0/31/11738-ssj_goku.jpg";
path[1] = "http://i.kinja-img.com/gawker-media/image/upload/arjw8wqvwnihalb6fq3k.png";
path[2] = "http://orig03.deviantart.net/8999/f/2013/167/1/7/sword_art_online_by_sakimichan-d69cxwk.jpg";

function ToggleRunning()
{
   running = !running;
   if (running)
     swapImage();
}
function swapImage()
{
   document.slide.src = path[i];
   if(i < path.length - 1) i++; else i = 0;
   if (running)
     setTimeout("swapImage()",3000);
}
window.onload=swapImage;
</script>
<img height="200" name="slide" src="image_1.gif" width="400" />
<button onclick="ToggleRunning();">Toggle</button>
</body>
</html>
```